# How to click on select options using selenium

Tags: java, selenium, select

I can't click on option element-

website: http://www.oferty.net

When I am trying to select one option in the drop-down list. Unfortunately
I receive the message:

> "Cannot click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function
>   returned an unexpected error"

What did I do wrong with the following code:

```
Select estateType = new Select(driver.findElement(By.id("ps_type")));
estateType.selectByVisibleText("domy");
```

Please help.

Comment: Try `estateType.selectByValue("2");`

Comment: The same.   Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptException: Cannot click on option element. Executing JavaScript click function returned an unexpected error, but no error could be returned from Internet Explorer's JavaScript engine. (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)

Answer (score 0):

I quicky check the HTML code of the dropdown you are trying to select and it's not a HTML dropdown. it's custom dropdpown created with CSS and so you can't use the default function provided by Selenium to select Dropdown Value.

```
<div class="jquery-selectbox-list jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced-list" style="width: 113px; height: 9em; display: none;">
<span class="jquery-selectbox-item value-998 item-0">rynek pierwotny
</span>
...
</div>
```

**Possible Solutions**

- Try SendKeys on `jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced-list` element and see if it's working, if not
- Click on `jquery-custom-selectboxes-replaced-list` and then scroll to the element you are interested in and click on it.

Answer (score 0):

It's a simulated dropdown list, not native. Selenium Select Class can only work on native dropdown list define by Select Tag. Even there is also embed a native dropdown, but it's hidden, that's why report can't click on option error. And When you operate on the dropdown from page, the embed native dropdown is always hidden, thus actually you not operated on the embed native one.

Try below code:

```
public void choosePsType(String psType) {
    // find the container node of the dropdown list
    WebElement psTypeSelect = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("label[for='ps_type'] + div"));

    // click on the selector to expand options
    psTypeSelect.findElement(By.cssSelector("span.jquery-selectbox-currentItem")).click();

    // choose wanted option
    String xpath = String.format(".//span[contains(@class, 'jquery-selectbox-item')][.='%s']", psType);
    psTypeSelect.findElement(By.xpath(xpath)).click();
}
```